# Security considerations when deploying Flask app to server

Tags: python, security, flask

This is my Flask app structure:

```
app/
    app.py
    static/
        static files
    secure/
        secret_file.ext
```

Is there any possible way of a hacker accessing `secret_file.ext` or even `app.py` itself, perhaps through a php script of some sort? If so, how can this be prevented?

Also, what are some other security considerations to keep in mind when deploying a Flask app to the web?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186308/flask-app-directory-and-permissions?rq=1

Comment: It really depends on your server's environment. Is it a Linux or windows running machine/firewall configuration/port forwarding scheme and many many other things that can influence the security of your data.

Comment: @Synaps I'm using Apache on Ubuntu, which I assume automatically does port forwarding for me. Also, I'm not sure about firewall configuration, it's just the default right now.

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything secure and save you should be aware of the latest news concerning network and system security.

Example of Linux vulnerability that many have heard about - [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29)

Another sensational vulnerability - [Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed)

---

However, here are some *fast* tips to go through:

- [Apache configuration](http://www.tecmint.com/apache-security-tips/)

Also enable **https** to encrypt connection

- [SSL/TLS Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)

I am not security guru, however I consider tip #14 not very constructive considering that ipv4 are in extreme short supply right now.

- [Linux security](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html)

If you are paranoid about security of your system

- [Linux Security Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003919)

You should also close all ports except for those being used by Apache and maybe ssh if you need to access your server from "outer web".

There is a lot to learn in system security, nevertheless I hope this will make your system stiff enough to that you could sleep in peace.